# Sequelize.js - Finding the rank of a row based on a column value

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

### The problem

With a single query, I want to be able to find a row in my database table, and generate a virtual column that denotes the "rank" of that column, based on the position it comes in when ordering of another column.

Let's say I have this table in a mySQL DB:

```
id | score
 1 | 400
 2 | 700
 3 | 200
 4 | 800
```

Now I want to look up the row with the id of 3, and figure out what rank this row is in terms of score.

Obviously, looking at the table, if rank is assigned from highest score to lowest, row 3 would get a rank of 4, because it has the lowest score out of the 4 rows in the table. **I do not want to `findAll` and sort in this case, because my real table is very large.**

### What I've tried

```
Model.findOne({
    attributes: [
      'id',
      'score',
      sequelize.literal('RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) rank')
    ]
  });
```

This gives me this error:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY score DESC) rank FROM `Model` AS `Model` LIMIT 1' at line 1",
```

I'd really appreciate any solutions / suggestions!

Edit: versions - mySQL 5.6, sequelize 4.35.2

Answer (score 0):

did you mean something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (

     SELECT id, score, rank from
    (
         SELECT id, score, @tmprank := @tmprank + 1 AS rank
        FROM scores
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @tmprank := 0) init 
        ORDER BY score DESC
    )  rt
    ORDER BY rank
) AS r
WHERE r.id = 3;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> select * from scores;
+----+-------+
| id | score |
+----+-------+
|  1 |   400 |
|  2 |   700 |
|  3 |   200 |
|  4 |   800 |
+----+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM (
    ->  SELECT id, score, rank from
    ->  (
    ->  SELECT id, score, @tmprank := @tmprank + 1 AS rank
    ->  FROM scores
    ->  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @tmprank := 0) init 
    -> ORDER BY score DESC
    ->  )  rt
    -> ORDER BY rank
    -> ) AS r
    -> WHERE r.id = 3
    -> ;
+----+-------+------+
| id | score | rank |
+----+-------+------+
|  3 |   200 |    4 |
+----+-------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works as raw SQL, but I was hoping to find an answer that uses Sequelize.js. Thanks nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by **counting objects above "object" I'm looking for a rank**.

```
const rank = await Game.count({
        where: {
            score: {
                [Op.gt]: game.score  // Op.gt it is syntax for grather then
            },       
        }
    })
rank++; // you have to add 1 to have the correct number
```

It's not the most efficient way, but it works.

Here are another Sequelizer's operators:
https://sequelizedocs.fullstackacademy.com/search-operators/

*Have fun*

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for it your approach is fine just syntax error
please find correct syntax bellow

```
Model.findOne({
attributes: [
  'id',
  'score',
  [sequelize.literal('RANK() OVER (ORDER BY "score" DESC)'), 'rank']
]});
```